# Android - Fragment animation obscured/not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I have a small test project with 2 fragments. FragmentOne loads when app is started.  Clicking the Fragment Two button, which should send FragmentOne out and bring FragmentTwo in, doesn't have the desired effect.  At the very bottom of the emulator screen, I can see a tiny bit of both frags move in and out correctly - but the full screen Fragment1 never goes away.

Here's the Java - each is its own file

```
//MainActiviy.java

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void selectFrag(View view) {
         Fragment fr;

         if(view == findViewById(R.id.button2)) {
             fr = new FragmentTwo();

         }else {
             fr = new FragmentOne();
         }

         FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
         FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

         ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.on_left_to_right, R.anim.off_left_to_right);
         ft.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr );
         ft.addToBackStack(null);
         ft.commit();
    }
}

    //FragmentOne.java

    public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      return inflater.inflate(
              R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
   }
}


//FragmentTwo.java

public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment{
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      return inflater.inflate(
              R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
   }
}
```

And the XML - each is its own file

```
   <!-- activity_main.xml -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            <!-- layoutStuff -->
            android:onClick="selectFrag" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button2"
            <!-- layoutStuff -->
             android:onClick="selectFrag" /> 

       <fragment
            android:name="com.help.me.FragmentOne"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- fragment_one.xml -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <!-- block of stuff -->
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                        <!-- block of stuff -->
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- fragment_two.xml -->

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" 
       android:orientation="horizontal">

           <TableLayout
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:columnCount="1"
               android:rowCount="2"
               android:id="@+id/infoTable">

                <TableRow 
                   android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                   <!-- layoutStuff --> >
                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/welcome"
                        <!-- layoutStuff -->  />   
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow 
                   android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                   <!-- layoutStuff -->  >
                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/id_image"
                        <!-- layoutStuff -->  />
                </TableRow>

           </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- res/anim/on_left_to_right.xml -->

    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="x" 
            android:valueType="floatType"
            android:valueFrom="1280"
            android:valueTo="0" 
            android:duration="500"/>
    </set>


    <!-- res/anim/off_left_to_right.xml -->

    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="x" 
            android:valueType="floatType"
            android:valueFrom="0"
            android:valueTo="-1280" 
            android:duration="500"/>
    </set>
```

This worked perfectly this morning.  Now I can't figure out what I added/changed/deleted that broke everything.

Comment: You can't replace fragments that were embedded in the xml layout. If you need to do transactions with them you have to declare them in code, programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly @Luksprog but I'm not sure I'm clear on your answer.

Two quick things:
• I have FragmentOne and FragmentTwo shown above, in the java code section.  Is that what you mean, or am I missing something else?

• This was working this morning.  No idea what I did, but I must have goofed up my undo/redo chain, 'cause I just couldn't get it back.

Comment: You have a fragment declared in the xml layout(with the `<fragment />`). You then try to do a replace transaction with this fragment from the xml. This doesn't work because a fragment declared in the xml layout can't be used in transactions like a replace transaction. So you need to remove the `<fragment />` from the activity's xml layout and add the initial `FragmentOne` in code in the `onCreate` method.

Comment: Thanks @Luksprog - Took me a bit, but I think I get what you're saying.  Thanks for taking the time to help out a newb.